# Combobox does not revert to null when value is cleared

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Due to a flaw in .NET (Microsoft says its intended but I see it as a serious flaw)
If a user empties a combo box (i.e. wants to blank out the value) the selected value does not revert to null instead it keeps the last valid selected value, so when you save with a blank combobox it goes back to the original value.One workaround is to first choose a different option from the drop down, then blank it out and it will work properly. However, that's not something users of an application would prefer.

So is there a way that I can fix this. Or is it possible that I can add an option for "NONE" which will then change the value in the database to NULL. Note: Combobox has data-binding and I was not able to add the option none for Names.

Contents of the Form.Desginer.cs:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      ......
      this.cmbSecCSR = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
      this.csrBindingSource2 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
      .....
       // 
        // pnlCSRs
        // 
        this.pnlCSRs.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.pnlCSRs.Controls.Add(this.cmbSecCSR);
        ......
       // 
        // cmbSecCSR
        // 
        this.cmbSecCSR.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.cmbSecCSR.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        this.cmbSecCSR.DataSource = this.csrBindingSource2;
        this.cmbSecCSR.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.cmbSecCSR.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cmbSecCSR.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 26);
        this.cmbSecCSR.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.cmbSecCSR.Name = "cmbSecCSR";
        this.cmbSecCSR.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 21);
        this.cmbSecCSR.TabIndex = 2;
        this.cmbSecCSR.ValueMember = "Username";

        this.cmbSecCSR.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox_TextChanged);
        this.cmbSecCSR.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbBox_Entered);
        // 
        // csrBindingSource2
        // 
        this.csrBindingSource2.DataMember = "CSR";
        this.csrBindingSource2.DataSource = this.productionDS;
        //..............
   }
```

Above are the bits and pieces related to this combobox (I'm just fixing bugs in the application, and a newbie in C#.

The contents related to this combobox in the .CS file are the following:

```
private void loadDetails()
   {
     this.productionCrewTableAdapter.FillByProductionID(this.productionDS.ProductionCrew, productionID);
cmbSecCSR.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", productionMasterBindingSource, "CSR2", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
  private void comboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmbx = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (cmbx.Equals(cmbCamSupplier))
        {

        }
        else if (cmbx.Equals(cmbLGSupplier))
        {

        }
        if (cmbx.Text.Length > 0) return;
        cmbx.ResetText();
        cmbx.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

 private void cmbBox_Entered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        String txt = cmb.Text;
        if (cmb.Name.Contains("CSR"))
        {
            if (cmb != null)
            {
                ((BindingSource)cmb.DataSource).Filter = (cmbOffice.SelectedIndex > -1 ? "Office = '" + cmbOffice.SelectedValue + "' AND " : "") + "IsCSR=1 AND Status=1";
                cmb.Text = txt;
            }
        }
        else if (cmb.Name.Contains("RC"))
        {
            int department = 0;
            if (cmb != null)
            {
                if (cmb.Name.Contains("Camera"))
                    department = 2;
                else if (cmb.Name.Contains("LG"))
                    department = 3;
                else if (cmb.Name.Contains("Power"))
                    department = 4;
                ((BindingSource)cmb.DataSource).Filter = (cmbOffice.SelectedIndex > -1 ? "Office = '" + cmbOffice.SelectedValue + "' AND " : "") + "IsCSR=0 AND Status=1 AND (Department = " + department + " OR Department is null OR Department = 0)";
                cmb.Text = txt;
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone can help me with this issue that I have been struggling with for a while, I'd really really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want users to type in values into the combo box, or would you want a non-editable drop down list of values (which could contain "none")?

Comment: So, this is your third attempt at this question? Have you finally got an answer?

Comment: No I haven't...hence the repost.... a None option would be good too Either or

Answer (score 0):

At the same time to your call clearing values with

```
this.cmbSecCSR.Items.Clear()
```

You have to do a

```
this.cmbSecCSR.Text = ""
```

or

```
this.cmbSecCSR.Text = "Default Text"
```

To clear the selected text in the combobox.

Comment: where would I put that in the code...in the comboBox_TextChanged function...??

Comment: In the TextChanged function, you have to use a :
this.cmbSecCSR.Text = "";
this.cmbSecCSR.SelectedValue = null;

After this, your combobox result will be null :)

Comment: I tried that....it compiled and gave me an exception error. and how would I put that exactly else if cmbx.Equals(cmbSecCSR)
and then if cmbx.Text="" <--- that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please HELP. I have been struggling with this for a while NOW.

Comment: It says cannot implicitly convert type 'String' to bool'

Comment: I think it's because you try to interpret "cmbx.Equals(cmbSecCSR)" as a string, but method Equals returns a boolean ... Or you try to interpret cmbx.Text in a IF condition... Gimme an example of your code

Comment: This is the exception that I get:

Error: Unhandled exception was caught

Execption Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
Exception Triggered by Method: Find


Exception Data 

No data provided

Comment: this is the else if statement that I added to the comboBox_Textchanged function:

 else if (cmbx.Equals(cmbSecCSR))
            {
                if (cmbSecCSR.Text == "")
                {
                    cmbSecCSR.SelectedValue = null;
                }
                
            }

when I run that I get the exception above when trying to delete the combobox value

Comment: Try to change SelectedValue by SelectedItem or set -1 to SelectedValue... I made a mistake ;)